# setting repetative properties for userform textboxes: Can this get done more easily?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Here is code I wrote that locks down userform textboxes when a condition is met. It has clear inefficiencies in the form of repetition:

```
    With txtESPPStock
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        .value = ""
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    With txtChildLife
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        .value = ""
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    With txtHealthcareFSA
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        .value = ""
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    With txtLtdPlusBuyUp
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        .value = ""
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    With txtMedicalDental
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        .value = ""
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    With txtSpouseLife
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        .value = ""
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    With txtStdPlusBuyUp
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        .value = ""
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    With txtSupplementalLife
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        .value = ""
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    With txtVision
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        .value = ""
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    With txt401kReg
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        .value = ""
        .Enabled = False
    End With
```

Since all the interior settings are the same, it seems like if I were only smart enough I could code it in many fewer lines. What I would want is to say, for each textbox, something like:

```
With txtESPPStock
    Call GetProperties
End With
```

Or even better, get all of the properties that need the property setting to sit in an array so I can do something like:

```
For txtFieldNumber = 0 To 15
    For PropertySettings = 0 To 3
        ArrayValue(txtFieldNumber, PropertySettings) = getproperty(PropertySettings)
    Next PropertySettings
Next txtFieldNumber
```

Maybe I'm close with the structure of this last one, yet I seem to lack some piece of knowledge that makes it clear to me how to do this.  Can anyone help straighten me out?

---

After learning you could loop through arrays in the same way as looping through ranges, I was able to slim down the code as I expected and make a tool that is reusable by other userforms without coding the settings again:

```
Sub SetLockedFields(ByRef arrLockedFields() As Variant)

    Dim varFieldToLock As Variant
        For Each varFieldToLock In arrLockedFields
            With frmPaycheckEntry.Controls(varFieldToLock)
                .Locked = True
                .BackColor = &H80000000
                .value = ""
                .Enabled = False
            End With
        Next

End Sub
```

To do all the work shown in my first code example above, I now just place the text fields  in a variant array and pass them, like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim arrLockedFields() As Variant
           .
           .
           .

        If <condition is met> Then
            ReDim arrLockedFields(1 To 11)
            arrLockedFields = Array("txtBasicLife", "txtChildLife", _
                                "txtESPPStock", "txtHealthcareFSA", _
                                "txtLtdPlusBuyUp", "txt401kReg", _
                                "txtMedicalDental", "txtSpouseLife", _
                                "txtStdPlusBuyUp", "txtSupplementalLife", _
                                "txtVision")
        End If

    Call SetLockedFields(arrLockedFields)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use a loop to avoid the repetition of codes.

```
Sub t1()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        'Check if the control is a textbox
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            With UserForm1.Controls(ctrl.Name)
                .Locked = True
                .BackColor = &H80000000
                .Value = ""
                .Enabled = False
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Another example: When you have certain names

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim names() As Variant
    Dim name As Variant
    names = Array("TextBox1", "TextBox2")
    For Each name In names
        With UserForm1.Controls(name)
            .Locked = True
            .BackColor = &H80000000
            .Value = ""
            .Enabled = False
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That is great. I did not know about the control method you use. I'll play around with it a little. Unfortunately, just some of the textboxes (not all of them) need to be locked down, so I need a way of calling just the ones that are relevant. +1 Upvote, but not exactly the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Yea I'm just stating the general method. Which are the specific ones you're looking for?

Comment: if you don't need all to be locked, then create another array with the exceptions then add a simple `if` statement inside sam092's loop.

Comment: thanks, Sam.  the array/loop combination is exactly what I was looking for: it makes total sense looking at it, but I didn't realize I could do the same with an array name/names loop as I have done many times with loops like `For Each Cell In RangeA`.

Comment: Thanks again, Sam. I added the code today that was made possible by your reply.